# Pl Sql developer get query results in new windows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am using the Oracle PL/SQL Developer. For certain queries it will be very useful if the results were shown in a new independent window. Previously, I saw a developer using this feature, but I don't know what parameter or configuration should be modified.

Comment: I added the [plsqldeveloper] tag, but I wonder - are you using *PL/SQL Developer*, produced by Allround Automation, or are you using *SQL Developer*, produced by Oracle? Thanks.

Comment: Hi how aer you ???, right now i am using sql developer produced by All round Automation, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there's no way to do this, unless the query you're executing is a linked query (i.e. you have a result set up and you're using the Linked Query toolbar button to show the data in related tables). If this is what you're trying to do, there's a setting on the Preferences dialog to open linked queries in a separate window. To change this setting, open the Tools menu, click on the Preferences... item, click on "SQL Window" under Window Types in the left-hand pane, and check the option labeled "Linked query in new window". Best of luck.

Share and enjoy.